# Temple Run on Android stores data in different place dependent on USB connection

Tags: android

When I play Temple Run on Android, the app stores data somewhere. If I enable a USB connection and then try playing the game, the app now stores this information somewhere completely new, so that my previous information is not visible any more. Only when I disable the USB connection does the previous data get used.

In other words, I start off as a completely new user if the SD card is mounted and am only able to resume my old state when the SD card is unmounted.

What kind of storage is this? Why is it not visible when I mount the SD card? Can I keep data when switching phones and keeping the SD card?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: But it is a question which intrigues me and other users on SO posiibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds Like it must be storing it on the SD Card, when you plug your phone into a USB port it mounts the SD Card to your computer not allowing access to it from your game... so the game will fallback onto internal storage (on phone).

When you plug your phone in it will be defaulting to mounting SD Card, Change this to "Just Charge" and try playing the game.

Answer (score 2):

They probably check if an SD-card is available, and if not use the internal storage.
When you mount the SD-card, the applications cannot access it, so it switches to internal storage, where you do not have any saved games.

Comment: Thanks Jave. However, when i browse my SD card to check if there are any related files, I can't find any. Any reason why this is so?

Comment: @OckhamsRazor I have no idea, maybe the files are hidden? You could try browsing for them in the DDMS file explorer in eclipse and see if you find anything.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor The Files are located in the following directory

Android\data\com.imangi.templerun\files